# sorting algorithm problem in Java; get wrong results

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Create in the class `MainProgram` a class method called `indexOfSmallestFrom`. It works similarly to the method in the previous section, but only considers the table values from a certain index forwards. In addition to the table, it receives this start index as a parameter.

In this example the first method call searches for the index of the smallest number, starting from index 0. Starting from index 0, the smallest number is -1 and its index is 0. The second method call searches for the index of the smallest value starting from index 1. In this case the smallest number is 6 and its index is 1. The third calls searches for the index of the smallest value starting at index 2. Then the smallest number is 8 and its index is 3.

the index should be printed for the smallest array.
According to the int array, my output should be:

```
1
1
4
```

but i get:

```
1
1
3
```

can't figure out logically, why.

```
public class MainProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] array = {3, 1, 5, 99, 3, 12};
        
        System.out.println(MainProgram.indexOfSmallestFrom(array, 0));
        System.out.println(MainProgram.indexOfSmallestFrom(array, 1));
        System.out.println(MainProgram.indexOfSmallestFrom(array, 2));
    }
    
    public static int indexOfSmallestFrom(int[] table, int startIndex){
        int count = startIndex;
        int indexOf = 0;
        int smallest = table[startIndex];
        for(int i = startIndex; i < table.length; i++){
            if(smallest > table[i]){
               smallest = table[i];
               count++;
            }
              indexOf = count; 
        }
            return indexOf;
    }   
 
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't setting `indexOf` only happen when you encounter a new smallest number? You might want to check the logical placement of `indexOf = count;`

Comment: Or you can just save your variable "I" whenever a new smallest item is found, then you don't have to work with "count".

Comment: Your logical mistake is that you now actually return startindex + the number of times a new minimum is found in your subarray (- 1 because your assignment of variable smallest).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just update indexOf when you find an element smaller than the value at the indexOf which is initially initialized as startIndex.

After iterating through all the values... return the finally updated indexOf.

```
// "static void main" must be defined in a public class.
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] array = {3, 1, 5, 99, 3, 12};

        System.out.println(indexOfSmallestFrom(array, 0));
        System.out.println(indexOfSmallestFrom(array, 1));
        System.out.println(indexOfSmallestFrom(array, 2));
    }

    public static int indexOfSmallestFrom(int[] table, int startIndex){
        int indexOf = startIndex;
        int smallest = table[startIndex];
        for(int i = startIndex; i < table.length; i++){
            if(smallest > table[i]){
               smallest = table[i];
               indexOf = i;
            }
        }
            return indexOf;
    }   
}
```

Comment: much appreciated. thats what i get for overthinking.

Comment: @FrancisAdewale Could you give me your first vote, Please?

Comment: @YashShah Lol I think he has downvoted you mistakenly xD

Comment: @saurabhgupta To downvote, one must have at least 125 rep points.

Comment: @YashShah yes, my bad